# Same code, executes through browser, throws a permission error through command line

Tags: apache-2.2, php, file-permissions

I've got an app that works fine in the browser, but when run through the command line, throws a permission error (related to folder creation).

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that it will run as the apache user when you execute it in the browser and as another  user when you started it from the command line, which might not have access rights in all the necessary directories.

Comment: Can I use the apache user through the command line?

Comment: Might be possible but is not recommended. Better try to fix your permissions.

Comment: @Emanuil Rusev .. you *could* try `su - apache` and then running it: but as SvenW said, it's not a good idea